# Why does my Spyder code only work in console?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I have never been more confused, when ran in the integrated console, line by line, my code works perfectly fine, but when ran from the IDE itself, it returns an empty list. (I'm using spyder).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://bonusbagging.co.uk/oddsmatching.php#')
test = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="data_table"]/tbody')))
print([i.text for i in test])
```